# spring security with angularJS web app and android app

Tags: android, angularjs, spring, google-maps, spring-security

I have angualrJS web app that recieves alerts from mobile app and marks the location of the mobile app user on google map. Once that mark is clicked info windo opens with name of user etc. 
BackEnd is java maven project, and using spring boot.
My question is:
When I add spring boot security, to authenticate the page this stops all communication and no alerts show at all....

Any suggestions:
At the moment this is the application.js

```
var app = angular.module('sos',['ngRoute','mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.config(['$httpProvider','$logProvider','$routeProvider',
function($httpProvider,$logProvider,$routeProvider) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { 
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    })
    .when('/download',{
        templateUrl: 'download.html'
    })
```

There is also a websocket connection that also stops and shows error 500 when I enable spring security...

This is web socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
 @EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(geoLocationHandler(), 
"/GeoLocationHandler").setAllowedOrigins("*");  
}       

@Bean
public GeoLocationHandler geoLocationHandler(){
    return new GeoLocationHandler();
}
```

Any suggestions why spring security stops the alerts and markers showing on the map on the web app? And the spring security would make websocket fail giving error 500?

I tried to extend WebSecurityConfigAdapter and add mathcers to home page etc didnt work, I tried cors filters didnt work, I tried csrf filters didnt work as well...Any suggestion would be appreciated....

Comment: Hello, SO and others SE site's are not a classic forum, it's a repository of knowledge in the form of Q&A, as such questions need to be focus enough and provide all elements within the questions. Which mean you should provide the code here.

Comment: Hi I posted code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091383/spring-security-preventing-rest-and-api-calls-in-angularjs-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this in your 
WebSecurityConfig.java file?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

(my snippet , try it and then remove what you don't like)
I think that eventually you don't let anyone to GET.

Here I give you also my Global method , in case you need it.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Comment: thanks Tsakiroglou, this will stop the GET as well, but I want to be able to access with authentication instead of getting the error, and now the webview on the mobile app will not open. Is there a way I can possibly leave security and just ask for user name and password for requests?

Comment: Have you test it?It is supposed to     .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

Comment: Can I ask you something?Do you save your sessions in order to give back xAuthentication?????

Comment: This is what I have:

Comment: @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
     .csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic()
     .and().authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/api/user/{userId}").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
 }

Comment: Thank you...The webapp is fine, I can use postman with authentication and access, but the problem is when I need to use the android app to alert or see alerts: how to authenicate from android app, for example if I have a webview of the page, it will come up with error page instead of authentication, I am still searching that...As I said I have only started to use Spring boot ...Not very familiar yet

Comment: Well I am not sure.Are you sure that the problem is not at Android's side?

Comment: not sure, communication between android and webapp was fine prior security, so I assume its in security configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after research I found that I needed to include http method get to be able to recive alerts on the the web app, so my websecurityConfiguration is like this:

```
    @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       .csrf().disable()                
       //.and()
       .httpBasic()
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests()                
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/geolocation/*").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/GeoLocationHandler").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/responser/*").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/").authenticated()
       .anyRequest().authenticated();                
}
```

Otherwise the webapp will not accept any alerts....
Hope this helps someone needing it....